# Excel VBA multiline textbox add extra lines in RTL language

Tags: excel, vba

When I have a multiline textbox fill in with RTL language (Hebrew) and I submit it to the sheet, the excel is sending the last word to the next line (as you can see in the image)[image]

The "submit" code is simple:

```
Range("f6").Value = TextBox1.Value
```

In English it does not occur.

Is this an Excel bug or i'm just missed some Properties settings ?

If someone want to test it with a Hebrew text, here is some text:

```
ניסיון לכתיבת טקסט
שורה נוספת לבדיקה
שורה שלישית של ניסיון
```

Comment: Is this what you are tryin? `Range("f6").Value = Replace(TextBox1.Value, Chr(13), "")`

Comment: שלום , try this: 
  Range("f6").Value = Replace(TextBox1.Value, vbNewLine, Chr(10))

Comment: Both of your suggestions work well, thank you